# Get Random Unique records from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have two tables

```
ds (parent table):  id, survey_id, village_id, mandal_id, district_id, status, assigned_to_user, created_at

ds_details (child table):  id, ds_id(foreign_key), sub_survey_id, crop_id, crop_variety_id
```

each parent have multiple child records

I have written the query like below for getting each group wise 30 records.

```
with group_mandal_wise_crops as (
                select distinct dd.id as detail_record_id, dd.crop_id, dd.variety_id, dd.sub_survey_id, d.id, d.survey_id, d.village_id, d.mandal_id, row_number() over(partition by d.mandal_id) as mandal_wise_rows
             from ds_details dd join ds d on d.id = dd.ds_id where dd.status = 0 and d.assigned_to_user is null
            )
   select distinct id, survey_id, village_id, mandal_id from group_mandal_wise_crops
   where mandal_wise_rows <= 30
```

I am getting each group-wise unique records but not getting exactly 30 records. because in some groups unique records are 10 or 15 only. I need each group wise 30 records mandatory. First, it needs to satisfy the unique condition and then after get the remaining records.

Based on the child and parent tables combination get the records from the parent table.

Please help me how to write a query in an efficient way

Comment: Can you provide a precise description of what you are trying to do?  That is hard to figure out with all the descriptions.

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL have different syntax.  Please choose only the DBMS that you are actually using.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I have updated the description, please have  a look

Comment: What if there aren't 30 records at all?  Sample data and desired results would help -- you don't need to use "30" for the example, 3 or 5 or whatever would suffice.